# google drive api upload success return id. but file not exist in drive?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

upload success with return id. and tried to drive.files.list that too. it exists. but file not exist in drive? what is this? I try to upload in specific folder by id. wheres file upload location?

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');
const credentials = require('./credentials.json');
const scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
];

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    credentials.client_email, null,
    credentials.private_key, scopes
);

const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

(async () => {
    
    const fileMetadata = {
        name: 'naruto.jpg'
    };

    const media = {
        mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
        body: fs.createReadStream('naruto.jpg')
    };

    const res = await drive.files.create({
        q: `'1PhND1fjEDnL63BbrLmw2V4M4B6jIfP8Q' in parents`,
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        fields: 'id'
    });

    console.log(res.data);
    
})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be using a service account.  A service account has its own google drive account and in your case you appear to have uploaded the file to the Service accounts google drive account.

If you want to upload the file to your own personal google drive account you should share a directory with the service account on your personal drive account and then when you create the file metadata make sure to set the parent directory where you would like the file uploaded to .

```
let fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'icon.png',
        'parents':  [  '10krlloIS2i_2u_ewkdv3_1NqcpmWSL1w'  ]
    };
```

Code ripped from [Upload Image to Google drive with Node Js](https://www.daimto.com/upload-image-to-google-drive-with-node-js/) also
[Google drive API upload file with Nodejs + service account](https://youtu.be/Z2MCxblgPoc)

Comment: I add already specific folder bind to a service. I bind a folder parent to my service account. then, i create subfolder. i upload that to that sub folder.

Comment: No you added a q parameter to the create method which does not take a q parameter. You need to set it in the file metadata as i have shown.

Comment: now it upload inside parent folder. So everything inside that parent dont belong to parent service account? so i need always set permission for every folder?

Comment: I try to upload to sub folder that still not set permission. it return error parents is not  folder.

Comment: The service account needs to have permissions on the folder you want it to upload to.  Everyone does you cant write to a place you dont have access to.

Comment: but that sub folder inside parent. it should automatically set permission belong to parent right?

Comment: depends upon who created it have you tried looking in google drive to see who has permissions on the sub folder you have created?   Have the service account create your sub folders maybe?

Comment: the only thing that makes me crazy on debuging this "parent" tag is forget to place the angle brackets.. your solution is great

Comment: The field is an array so you can put it in more than one folder at the same time.   Thats the point of the brackets 